# Slide first image from bottom and transition fade into second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have an ordinary front page where I would like to have 2 background images alternating (fade between transition) **in the center** at the top.
Its all good but when first image is loaded it will slide from the left but I need to slide it **from bottom**. How can I do it? 
Flickering after first image occurs only in JSFiddle for some reason, in localhost is fine.

```
<div id="frontpage-carousel">

    <div class="container text-center">
         something something
    </div>

</div>

#frontpage-carousel {
  transition: background 1.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 1.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 1.5s linear;
  -o-transition: background 1.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: background 1.5s linear;
}

.first {
  background: #000 url(http://placehold.it/350x420) no-repeat top center;
}

.second {
  background: #000 url(http://placehold.it/350x350) no-repeat top center;
}
```

JS code here only periodically changes class of div

```
(function($) {
    setTimeout(function (){

     var images = ['first', 'second'];
    var classIndex = -1;

    function changeBackground() {

        // Grab the element
        var main = $("#frontpage-carousel");

        // If this isn't the first time, remove the previous class
        if (classIndex >= 0) {
            main.removeClass(images[classIndex]);
        }

        // Update the index, wrapping around when we reach the end of the array
        classIndex = (classIndex + 1) % images.length;

        // Add the new class
        main.addClass(images[classIndex]);
    }

    changeBackground();
    setInterval(changeBackground, 3000);

}, 1000); 




})(jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxvjgavt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**css:**
add this to `#frontpage-carousel` style block :

```
background-position: bottom center;
```

**js:** and the following to your js :

```
// Add the new class
    main.addClass(images[classIndex]).css({'background-position': 'top center'});
```